# Give way applies when 2 lines + 2 lines join to same way?

Tags: driving, azerbaijan

[image]

If I am coming from top to bottom turning as big arrow shows do I need to give way to the people coming from right ?  or no need because there is 4 lines for each.

There is no signs that say anything in both ways.

From top to bottom its all one way , to the right is all one way , from bottom to top its two ways . all cars from top to bottom and bottom to top turn and go to one way street with 4 lines.

Comment: Is the road both arrows are turning in to one-way or two-way?

Comment: @Rick From top to bottom its all one way , to the right is all one way , from bottom to top its two ways . all cars from top to bottom and bottom to top turn and go to one way street with 4 lines.

Comment: Both directions have 2 lanes following into 2 lanes on one side and 2 lanes on the other side so there is no question of anyone giving way to anyone else - they all have their own lane. If someone decides to then switch lanes the usual lane-changing rules apply which is that the vehicle already in the lane has right of way. So someone entering from the bottom who then swerves left into a different lane (or vice versa) is clearly in violation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any relevant Azerbaijani rules of the road, but on the assumption that they follow the general principles as the UK -

Both vehicles enter the four-laned one-way road to the right, travelling within their own clearly marked lanes so there is no reason for them to give way (called "yield" in some places) to one another,  or anyone else, unless they intent to change lane.

The UK's [Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code) includes the following:

> **Rule 131**
>
> Lane dividers.  These are short, broken white lines which are used on wide carriageways to divide them into lanes. You should keep between them.

> **Rule 133**
>
> If you need to change lane, first use your mirrors and if necessary take a quick sideways glance to make sure you will not force another road user to change course or speed. When it is safe to do so, signal to indicate your intentions to other road users and when clear, move over.

> **Rule 143**
>
> One-way streets ... Choose the correct lane for your exit as soon as you can. Do not change lanes suddenly ...